# Relative filename in ERB files

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am putting my ERB files in app/view. The problem is that sometimes I make mistakes when including CSS and JS files. I refer to them as "js/include.js" or "css/default.css" instead of /js/include.js and /css/default.css

However, these files are located in the public directory not the app/views directory so as a result the page breaks.

Is there a way to change the default behavior so that it looks in public folder whenever I refer to these files relatively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you stick with the Rails conventions you'll save yourself some grief. Use `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag` in your layouts. And don't scatter css and js includes around your views. Use custom layouts instead.

For example, if you have an admin interface with a different look and different behavior you could add app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb. Then, in AdminController specify that it should use the admin layout. You can also specify the layout at the controller action level if you need to.